# Analog System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject in .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core-rc2, .net-core

I am trying to port project to .NET Core. But I can't find analog  System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject.

Answer (score 3):

The [`ExpandoObject`](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Dynamic.Runtime/src/System/Dynamic/ExpandoObject.cs) class lives in the [System.Dynamic.Runtime](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Dynamic.Runtime/) package, along with `DynamicObject` and other dynamic infrastructure types.

Tip: you can use this [package search](http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/) website to find types in .NET Core - it still works with RC2 packages but just download the stable version in stead of `*-rc2`.

Comment: It is available for netstandard now.